# Struct definida no arquivo.c auxiliar (com definição de funções e structs) não é reconhecida no main

Tags: c, struct, gcc, makefile

Estou fazendo um projeto em C, e tenho 3 arquivos:

1 .c  contendo as definições de funções e structs.

1 .h contendo os protótipos dessas funções e structs

ae1 .c que contém o main.

No .c com as definições, eu defini a struct:

```
typedef struct vector {

    int numDePosicoes;
    double vetor[5000];

}ESTRUCT;
```

E no método main, eu tento criar uma instância dessa struct 
da seguinte maneira:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

    ESTRUCT vetor;

    //criando separadamente um ponteiro para a struct
    ESTRUCT *ponteiroPraVetor = &vetor;
```

Mas o gcc acusa o erro: "error: unknown type name ‘ESTRUCT’"

Tanto na criação da struct, quando na criação do ponteiro para ela.

Obs: Eu estou usando um Makefile para montar o programa, segue ele abaixo:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall

Roteiro5exe:    mainr5.o    Roteiro5.o

mainr5.o:   mainr5.c    Roteiro5.h

Roteiro5.o: Roteiro5.c  Roteiro5.h

clean:
    rm *.o
```

OBS: Quando eu coloco todo o código no mesmo arquivo, e simplesmente compilo ele, dá certo. Talvez o problema esteja no makefile. Alguém consegue enxergá-lo?

Comment: Ah, o conteúdo do arquivo.h é esse:    void inicializa_vetor(struct vector *v1);
struct vector vetor;

Comment: Includes colocados nos dois arquivos .c: o de definições e o do main: #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: Mas você está fazendo ``include`` do arquivo onde você definiu a ``struct``?? Parece que não...

Comment: Cristian, no arquivo.h eu fiz eu coloquei o "protótipo" da struct (nem sei se precisa). Que é o Seguinte:   struct vector nomeQualquerDeStruct e no arquivo.c (sem o main) eu coloque a struct completa (  typedef struct estructe{ ..... } ESTRUCT, completa com seu conteúdo.  O que você quer dizer com definir? Declarar a struct completa?

Comment: Esquece, já vi a resposta. Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Você tem a definição no header

```
typedef struct vector {

    int numDePosicoes;
    double vetor[5000];

}ESTRUCT;
```

E o uso em `main`

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

    ESTRUCT vetor;

    //criando separadamente um ponteiro para a struct
    ESTRUCT *ponteiroPraVetor = &vetor;
```

E o que tem `1.c`?

E

- numDePosicoes é `int` mas se é o que parece não pode ser negativo. Prefira `unsigned` ou `size_t` que existe para isso
- `ESTRUCT` é o nome para a `struct`. Nomes com todas as letras em maiúscula são em geral reservados para constantes e é o que quem for ler seu programa espera. Nomes definidos pelo usuário costumam ter a Primeira letra maiúscula apenas. Ou um prefixo tipo `t_` por exemplo.
- `vector` é também o nome da `struct` e que tem um campo chamado `vetor`, só que ela podia ser anônima
- em `main` declara `vetor` como `ESTRUCT` estática e aí declara um ponteiro `ponteiroPraVetor` com o endereço de ... `vetor`

Tudo isso é MUITO confuso e frágil.

Vou deixar um exemplo do simples em C para esse seu caso e você pode comparar

#### A `struct`

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    double* V;

}   Vetor;
```

Esse é o normal: ao invés de alocar 5.000 `double` toda vez, e ter um campo na `struct` dizendo que vai usar p. ex. `8`.

E já se escrevem as funções para criar e destruir um trem desses, no estilo `RAAI` de `C++`. Isso torna a sua vida mais tranquila. O mínimo

```
Vetor* cria_v(unsigned);
Vetor* apaga_v(Vetor*);
```

E claro que vai querer ver o que tem dentro para testar então já escreve uma função que faz isso.
E claro que seria legar ter uns valores diferentes e que possa reproduzir então seria conveniente ter uma função que fizesse isso. Então escrevemos

```
int    mostra_v(Vetor*,unsigned,unsigned,const char*);
Vetor* fabrica_v(unsigned);
```

#### o header `1.h`

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    double* V;

}   Vetor;

Vetor* cria_v(unsigned);
Vetor* apaga_v(Vetor*);
int    mostra_v(Vetor*,unsigned,unsigned,const char*);
Vetor* fabrica_v(unsigned);
```

E um teste já podia ser

#### `main` para um teste

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "1.h"

int main(void)
{
    srand(220913);
    Vetor* tst = cria_v(5000);
    mostra_v(tst, 0, 4, "5 primeiros valores");
    tst = apaga_v(tst);
    // agora cria um vetor de teste com fabrica_v()_

    tst = fabrica_v(20);
    mostra_v(tst, 15, 19, "ultimos valores de teste");
    tst = apaga_v(tst); // apaga de novo
    return 0;
}
```

Que cria e apaga um vetor de 5000 e depois um de 20 com a tal função `fabrica_v()`. E usa `mostra_v` para ver o conteúdo.

#### Saída desse exemplo

```
5 primeiros valores
  [Vetor tem 5000 elementos]:
      0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00
ultimos valores de teste
  [Vetor tem 20 elementos]:
     87.25       44.76       29.88       26.44       57.38
```

#### Uma implementação de `1.c`

As funções tem umas poucas linhas.

- Em `cria_v()` o's elementos do vetor são zerados, porque eu preferi
- Eu sempre uso cast para o retorno de `malloc()` porque conversões implícitas como essa são um risco. Antes de me lembrarem disso lembro aos vigilantes do SO que o C-FAQ é uma referência dos anos 90

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "1.h"

// cria o vetor com sz caras
Vetor* cria_v(unsigned sz)
{
    if (sz < 1) return NULL;
    Vetor* novo = (Vetor*)malloc(sizeof(Vetor));
    if (novo == NULL) return NULL; // nao alocou
    novo->size = sz;
    novo->V    = (double*)malloc(sz * sizeof(double));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; i += 1)
        novo->V[i] = 0.;
    return novo;
}

// apaga 'vetor' e retorna NULL
Vetor* apaga_v(Vetor* vetor)
{
    if (vetor == NULL) return NULL;
    free(vetor->V);  // apaga o vetor de double
    free(vetor); // apaga o vetor
    return NULL;
}

// mostra o conteudo do vetor na tela para as posicoes
// entre ini e fim inclusive. 'tit' um titulo opcional
int mostra_v(
    Vetor* vec, unsigned ini,
    unsigned fim, const char* tit)
{
    if(vec == NULL) return -1;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    printf("  [Vetor tem %d elementos]:\n", vec->size);
    for (unsigned i = ini; i <= fim; i += 1)
        printf("%10.2f  ", vec->V[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

// cria um vetor preenchido com porcentagens 
// aleatorias para testar
Vetor* fabrica_v(unsigned sz)
{
    Vetor* nv = cria_v(sz);
    if (nv == NULL) return NULL;  // deu pau
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; i += 1)
        nv->V[i] = (double)(rand() % 100)/100. +
                   (double)(rand() % 100);
    return nv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você está confundindo declaração com definição. Sempre que você quer usar alguma coisa, você precisa declará-la. Declarar significa introduzir algo para o sistema. Por exemplo:

```
extern int a;
typedef struct { int a;} X;
void print();
```

Definir significa dar um corpo para as declarações. Pode imaginar como criando um espaço em memória, onde as declarações irão viver. Por exemplo:

```
int a = 1;
X k;
void print() {}
```

As definições, normalmente, são colocadas em um arquivo .c, enquanto que as declarações, normalmente, são colocadas em um arquivo .h. Isso é necessário porque sempre que for usar uma definição, você tem que ver a declaração.

Por isso que, no seu caso, a declaração do `ESTRUCT` está no lugar errado. Isso não é uma definição, é uma declaração e ela deve ser vista em todos os arquivos onde se queira usá-la. Portanto, você deve declará-la em um arquivo .h e incluir esse arquivo onde está a função `main` que por sinal, é onde você faz uma definição ao escrever:

```
ESTRUCT vetor;
```

Comment: Entendi, mas no meu arquivo que contém o MAIN, qual é a sintaxe pra incluir o meu .h? É a mesma dos .h da linguagem? =   Ex:   #include <stdio.h>    Tentei isso com meu .h, mas deu "fatal error".

Comment: Tente `#include "arquivo.h"`